# Is Caching necessary when using Custom Annotations in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, annotations, doctrine

In my Syfmony 4.1 project, I'm using Custom Annotations to apply some meta data to some Value Objects.  I'm following the [Doctrine Annotation Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/index.html), which (I think) is assuming that you're using Doctrine as a stand alone package.

However, it seems to me that Symfony is handing some of the [Annotation Setup](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/annotations.html#handling-annotations) for you.  As an example, the documentation talks about using its own autoloading mechanism rather than the one provided by PHP / Composer.  Symfony seems to handle this automatically.

The documentation talks about [Annotation Readers](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/annotations.html#setup-and-configuration) and recommends caching your Annotations with either a `FileCacheReader` or Doctrine `AppCache`.  I'm assuming that Symfony is using one of these mechanisms (or it's own caching mechanism) to cache Symfony's built in Annotations.

My question is this:  Does Symofny automatically handle the caching of Custom Annotations, or do I need to cache them manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony takes care the caching of doctrine annotations through the doctrine bundle configuration:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: array #this is the option to configure
        query_cache_driver: array
        result_cache_driver: array
```

The `metadata_cache_driver` options define the cache driver that symfony uses to cache the annotations.

All you have to do is to configure this option properly to have your annotations cached.

More on how to properly configure the cache driver options in [documentation.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers)